# fastreport v2.5 filter expression

Tags: delphi, fastreport

[image]

I'm end user and I want to edit in the app report to show me the absent one day as the Picture, what is wrong ?

The application used fast report for Delphi/c++ builder v 2.5

Comment: If you wanted to assign a value 1 to that field, use `:=` instead of `=`.

Comment: i want filter the data to sort in report to show me the absent one day